# A secure single site JWT implementation

Tags: security, web, cookies, jwt, token

I read a lot about JWTs and found that it is pretty hard to use them in a secure CSRF and XSS proof way.
Until I realized that my tokens will probably not leave my unique domain...
This led me to this idea of implementation:

1. Use a refresh token along with an access token. That way I can set short expiring time to the access token and limit the database calls to verify the user and only when the access token expires a simple verification by asking the database that the refresh token is not blacklisted before sending a new access token to the user.
2. I understood that if I store a token in the local/session storage it would be vulnerable to XSS attacks but if I store it in an HTTP-only cookie it would be vulnerable to CSRF attacks.
3. As I don't need to access the token inside the JavaScript and that I only need this token in one website, I thought that I could store the access token inside an HTTP-only cookie (that way it is protected from XSS) along with the secure flag and the same site flag set to strict (preventing CSRF).
4. And regarding the refresh token I could store it inside an HTTP-only cookie that has the same secure flag but without the same site flag this time. Because the server will never execute any action only based on the refresh token, I think that it will therefore not be susceptible to CSRF attacks. The only thing the server will do with a refresh token is to send back a new access token which, if I understood it well, could not be read from the CSRF attacker. The CSRF vulnerability allows the attacker to make a request to the server (which will automatically contain HTTP-only cookies) but he cannot read the response of this request.

I don't know if this implementation of JWTs would be secure or if I missed something...

This is what I'm asking you (JWTs and web security experts) would that be a good JWTs implementation ?

Comment: I think you just need a plain old session id with server-side sessions. A JWT has about zero benefit for your usecase, but the complexity does not help security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a word on JWTs. An oldschool plain server-side session (with a long, random session id, correctly stored in a secure, httpOnly, maybe also SameSite cookie) is "more secure" than any JWT in most cases. The reason is that JWTs store state on the client, where it is more available to an attacker, offline attacks can be performed against the cryptography involved, also JWTs are plain text and only their integrity is protected (ie. they are protected against client-side change, but not against looking at the contents by default, though you could use JWE, and encrypted JWT too). Last but not least, implementation is more complex, and simplicity is great for security.

So you would use a JWT when you need a benefit that it provides.

One argument is that it's stateless. This is very often overrated though. First, in most applications the bottleneck will not be the database lookup needed to find the session data in the database. In some very high profile, high traffic applications it actually might be, but you are probably not developing something like that every day. Usually it's just ok to do a database lookup, and it makes the whole thing a lot simpler. Second, sometimes you need token revocation, ie. you want to be able to force-logout a user. Even if you used a JWT for statelessness, you would have to store *something* in a database, a list of revoked tokens for example, and checking that would also be a database roundtrip. Revoking JWTs simply cannot be implemented in a purely stateless way.

Another benefit is that you can use it for multiple origins. If you get a httpOnly session cookie, that will be managed by the browser, javascript cannot send it to other origins, like an API or something - that's the whole point, JS not having access. But sometimes you do need that, especially in single sign-on scenarios, where you have an identity provider (a component that provides logon), and services (eg. APIs) that you want to use your access token on. In this case a classic cookie would not work, and JWTs are very handy.

So in short, you would use a JWT when you really need statelessness, or the option to send the token to multiple origins. As a rule of thumb, if you can store the JWT in a httpOnly cookie, you most probably don't need it at all, and could just use a plain old server-side session.

And then let's say you decide to use JWTs, what about refresh tokens. They are another generally misunderstood feature of token-based authentication. The point in using refresh tokens is to be able to use short-lived access tokens, so if an access token get s compromised, it is at least time limited. But if you store the refresh token the same way as an access token, why would an attacker not get that too?

It only makes sense to have a refresh token, if you store it differently, otherwise you could just have long-lived access tokens, and that would not be less secure.

One typical thing is to have an identity provider ("login server", or IdP) that sets a refresh token (or just a plain old session id) in a httpOnly cookie for the identity provider origin, so whenever the client makes a request to the IdP, it "just works" if they are already logged in, and can provide a new access token without user interaction. The access token is then stored in something like localStorage (for the service origin), susceptible to XSS, but at least time limited. If you don't have this separation, a separate refresh token probably doesn't  make much sense.

As a final note, all of this should very rarely be implemented by yourself. Any language or framework you use probably already has one or more known good, maintained implementation for authentication. You should just use those, but it's still very much worth to understand it of course.

Please note that in any actual application there might be subtleties and certain circumstances that somewhat change what you want to do, but the above is a general way to think about secure authentication.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right, I should use sessions... I was attracted by the stateless side of JWTs but as I need revocation it isn't worth it... On top of that it's probably not that much of a cost to run a db query on each request.